# SQL Query structure example for recursive lookup

Tags: sql

I'm struggling a bit with this query.  Perhaps someone can give me a hint?

My setup consists of 3 tables (Actors, Movies, and Relations). What I want to do is:

> Find all actors whose name starts with an A that play in any movie alongside Person1.

That's how far i got:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM Actors a, Movies m, Relations r 
WHERE a.Name='A%' 
AND Person1.keyPerson = m.KeyPerson 
AND m.KeyMovies ....
```

An example on how to continue would be nice!

UPADATE - tables look like this:

Actors (actorsID, name) 
Movies (moviesID, title)
Relations (actorsID, moviesID)

Comment: Please provide the structure of the tables. You have provided nothing for `Relations`.

Comment: Please show your table structure.  I can't figure out how these tables relate to each other.

Comment: You could use 5 inner joins between actors to relations to movies the relations r2 to movies to actors a2 and put your conditions in the diferrent sections.  Or you could do w where EXISTS (with a selects)...or...lots of combinations. Give it a try update here with test data and expected result.  And primary keys of tables!

Comment: Please don't post the structure in the comments.  Use the Edit button to update your original post.

Comment: Would recommend using explicit joins so it is easier to distinguish your join criteria from your filtering criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this - one method you can do is via an `IN` statement, pulling the movies `Person1` has been in, and checking the `A%` person's movies.

```
Select  Distinct A.Name
From    Actors      A
Join    Relations   R   On  R.ActorId = A.ActorId
Where   A.Name Like 'A%'
And     R.MovieId In
(
    Select  R2.MovieId
    From    Actors      A2
    Join    Relations   R2  On  R2.ActorId = A2.ActorId
    Where   A2.Name = 'Person1'
)
```

Another method is via an `EXISTS` statement, looking for any movies that `Person1` has been in that `A%` has also been in:

```
Select  A.Name
From    Actors      A
Join    Relations   R   On  R.ActorId = A.ActorId
Where   A.Name Like 'A%'
And Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    Movies      M2
    Join    Relations   R2  On  R2.MovieId = M2.MovieId
    Join    Actors      A2  On  R2.ActorId = R2.ActorId
    Where   A2.Name = 'Person1'
    And     M2.MovieId = R.MovieId
)
```

Comment: Thanks - i will try that

Answer (score 0):

A solution without subquery:

```
SELECT     DISTINCT a.Name
FROM       Actors a
INNER JOIN Relations r
        ON r.actorsID = a.actorsID
INNER JOIN Relations r2
        ON r.moviesID = r2.moviesID
INNER JOIN Actors a2
        ON a2.actorsID = r2.actorsID
       AND a2.Name = 'Person1'
WHERE      a.Name LIKE 'A%'
```